# Integers $a$ such that for every integer $n$ the sum of digits of $na$ is odd

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem but without success:

> For every integer $a$ there exist an integer $n$ such that the sum of digits of $na$ is odd

Do you have any suggestion about this problem, thanks.

Comment: Why does the title contradict what you ask in the body of the Question?  Even if the problem can logically be posed in either way, using the contradictory formulations confuses this Reader.

Comment: @Now the title and the body aren't even each others' negations any more. Do you want an odd digit sum for _every_ $n$ or just for _some_ $n$?

Comment: Yes i corrected it, just for some $n$

Comment: There is a significant disconnect between the title and body.  The title *seems* to ask if there exists $a$ s.t. for all $n$ the sum of digits of $na$ is odd, while the body asks if for all $a$, there exists $n$ s.t. the sum of digits is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not true** when $a=0$. However, assuming that $a$ is positive:

Without loss of generality we can assume that $a$ has no trailing zeroes.

If the *next-to-last* digit is $9$, then multiply by $11$. This leaves the last digit unchanged and makes sure the next-to-last one isn't $9$ anymore.

Call the last two digits at this stage $c$ and $d$.

Multiply by $100k+1$ for an appropriate $k$ that makes the *first* digit $(10-d)$. This is always possible -- by choosing $k$ large enough each increase in $k$ increases the product by little enough to change the first digit by at most one step at a time. The two last digits are still $c$ and $d$.

Multiply by $10^{m-1}+1$, where $m$ is the number of digits in our number. Then the final $d$ in one copy of the number gets added to the leading $(10-d)$ in the other, producing zero with a carry into $c$. The carry stops here because $c$ is not $9$. All the other digits simply get duplicated, so the digit sum is $$(10-d)+(\text{middle digits})+(c+1)+0+(\text{middle digits})+c+d$$ which is odd as required.